# Unsupervised clustering of sequence of events to subsequences

Tags: time-series, clustering, unsupervised-learning, sequence-analysis, subset

I have a big dataset of `M` sequences of `[1 - N]` events, where each event has multiple properties (start date, end date, location, and more contextual features).

For each sequence of `[1-N]` events I want to find up to K `(1<=K<=N)` subsequences (clusters) based on events similarity.

For example, the sequence of the following events: `[A B C D]`

```
EVENT     START_DATE     END_DATE       LON      LAT

A         2018-01-01     2018-01-02     10       15
B         2018-01-02     2018-01-03     10       15
C         2018-02-01     2018-01-08     20       30
D         2018-03-01     2018-03-03     10       15
```

can be split into:

`[[A] [B] [C] [D]]`,`[[A B] [C] [D] ]`, `[[A][B C][D]]`, `[[A] [B] [C D]]`, `[[A B] [C D]]`, `[[A B C][D]]`,`[[A] [B C D]]`, `[[A B C D]]`

Where the obvious split is `[[A B][C][D]]` since `A` and `B` are consecutive in same location with similar time-span, `C` happens a month after in a different location and `D` happens in the same location but 2 month later.

Some assumptions/special treatment might apply:

- Same clusters appear sequentially in terms of time (`[[A C] [B] [D]]` is not possible)
- Different features might have different weights (time proximity might be more important that date proximity
- Number of clusters is unknown
- Ground truth is unknown, but can be determined in a quite accurate way by human labelling.
- The calculation needs to be realtime (<1s for M<100), but can be calculated incrementally (recalculated after addition of a new event)

Any suggestions of what algorithm can be useful for this problem? Classical clustering here is not suitable and I'm looking for other options.

Answer (score 1):

Try *generalized* DBSCAN.

Define two thesis:

1. Distance, points sold be "near" each other
2. Time, events should be close in time

Don't use a standard implementation. Instead exploit that you can sort the data by time, and only need to consider the events within the time threshold.

Comment: I'm sorry but I can't see how it relates to *frequent subsequence*. I'm not looking for the popular subsequences (they probably won't repeat at all), but looking how to group events in the sequence into clusters.
(reference for FS - http://ai.ms.mff.cuni.cz/~sui/sequential_mining.pdf)

Comment: Then you need to explain your problem better, what kind of patterns you are looking for.

Comment: So give examples of the actual input and output, not A B C if these aren't items in a sequence, and how a cluster is supposed to be defined.